# Kotlin how to use js in a webview containing xml file and css

Tags: javascript, css, xml, kotlin, webview

i am building an app where in one activity i have webview and i have an xml file that i display in this webview. i declare it like this :

```
 val destination = context?.getFilesDir()?.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "/$article.xml"
 var filedest = File(destination)
   
 if (!filedest.exists())
     return

 val webSetting = webView.settings
 webSetting.builtInZoomControls = true
 webSetting.javaScriptEnabled = true
 webSetting.textZoom = 100

 webView.loadUrl("file:///" + destination)
```

With this i set the websetting that i want for my webview and i can display my xml file and it work perfectly.

Now i would like to style my text so in my xml i added a line to use a css file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="article.css"?>
```

With the associate file i was able to style my xml.

The problem is that now i would like to add some kind of js on top of my css so that the user could modifie some style by himself for exemple the fontsize of the background color. So i would like to have some button on my actionbar that would trigger a script in js that would modifie the fontsize for exemple.

I tried to follow this from android developer : [https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#:~:text=your%20Android%20app.-,Bind%20JavaScript%20code%20to%20Android%20code,to%20display%20a%20Dialog%2C%20instead%20of%20using%20JavaScript%27s%20alert()%20function.,-To%20bind%20a](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#:%7E:text=your%20Android%20app.-,Bind%20JavaScript%20code%20to%20Android%20code,to%20display%20a%20Dialog%2C%20instead%20of%20using%20JavaScript%27s%20alert()%20function.,-To%20bind%20a)

But i couldn't make it work. i tried to add the script in the beginning of my xml but instead of adding a button to send a toast, it just added it as text in my xml. Maybe it doesn't work with xml ?

So in the end i would like to use something to trigger some modification on my webview from my actionbar. I still think that js might be a good option but i couldn't make it work. i am also open to any other idea.

**EDIT**

For exemple i want to change the background color so i try :

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("document.body.style.background = 'blue';", null)
```

But it doesn't change the background.

Comment: Can you also add your JavaScript code parts? It probably contains some hints about the problem.

Comment: i tried to change the background color for exemple

Answer (score 0):

I think you take a bad way. When you make an app native with kotlin the webview its only a alternative for create UI, in any case you can replicate the behavior of a classic webpage. The code for interact with the webview its only kotlin o Java, the javascript its only a bridge for comunicate between the html and your Kotlin (Java) code.

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function showAndroidToast(toast) {
            Android.showToast(toast);
        }
    </script>
```

As you can see the javascript its only use for call android native code.
I hardly recomend you to use a framework like flutter / cordova if you dont know about kotlin code.